# Where can I find problems with solutions about tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, tensor-products, book-recommendation, tensors

I would like to find a book or webpage with solved problems on tensors, as they are used in the fields of differential geometry and general relativity. I would prefer sources that are freely available, if possible

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of tensors?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook tensors that you use for differential geometry and general relativity, thanks for ask.

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz This seems like a reasonable question. I'm not sure why it was closed. It doesn't seem too broad, so it may be that the voters are reacting negatively to the poor quality of the English. If that's the problem, then you might ask the question this way: "I would like to find a book or webpage with solved problems on tensors, as they are used in the fields of differential geometry and general relativity. I would prefer sources that are freely available, if possible." Also, please note that you are permitted to ask questions in Spanish. Usually, someone will translate them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want: http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=en&blang=en&page=Book&id=157357 http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=en&blang=en&page=Book&id=199813

Comment: @user49640 thanks

Comment: @user49640 you have that books in pdf or djvu format

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz The only versions I've seen on the internet are in Russian.

Comment: Actually, I'm not recommending those books particularly. I'm not sure they have problems in them, so you still need to ask other people.

Comment: @user49640 I buy the book https://www.amazon.com/Geometr%C3%ADa-Riemanniana-an%C3%A1lisis-tensorial-T/dp/5396006846 i trust in your word

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz I'm not recommending the book. I'm suggesting that you have a look at it (in a library, for example) to determine whether it's suitable for you.